# Parse file to hex

Tags: c++

Assume that I have a file .img. I want to parse the file and display it by hex. This is my code reference in the internet. But the application display is null. Please help me to resolve it.

```
     int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
      {
    const char *filename = "test.img";
    ifstream::pos_type size;
    char * memblock;
    ifstream file(filename, ios::in|ios::binary|ios::ate);
      if (file.is_open())
      {
        size = file.tellg();
        memblock = new char [size];
        file.seekg (0, ios::beg);
        file.read (memblock, size);
        file.close();

        std::string tohexed = ToHex(std::string(memblock, size), true);
        cout << tohexed << endl;
      }
      }


        string ToHex(const string& s, bool upper_case)  { 


    ostringstream ret;

    for (string::size_type i = 0; i < s.length(); ++i)
    {
        int z = (int)s[i];
        ret << std::hex << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << (upper_case ? std::uppercase : std::nouppercase) << z;
    }

    return ret.str();
}
```

Comment: `But the application display is null.` That is not true. The code as shown will not compile.

Comment: Is file actually open? Because if it's not open, nothing would show, and it's sounds like that's what's happening.

Comment: Put a breakpoint at the beginning of `main` and single step through your code.

Answer (score 3):

That's way too much code.

It can help to define a class with `operator<<` to encapsulate custom formatting.

https://ideone.com/BXopcd

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iomanip>

struct hexchar {
    char c;
    hexchar( char in ) : c( in ) {}
};
std::ostream &operator<<( std::ostream &s, hexchar const &c ) {
    return s << std::setw( 2 ) << std::hex << std::setfill('0') << (int) c.c;
}

int main() {
    std::copy( std::istreambuf_iterator<char>( std::cin ), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(),
        std::ostream_iterator< hexchar >( std::cout ) );
}
```

Comment: @Johnsyweb well, that makes the cast implicit. I can eliminate the cast, and simplify the program, by doing the hex conversion without iostreams. `static char hextable[] = "0123456789abcdef"; s << hextable[ c >> 4 ] << hextable[ c & 15 ];` That requires `unsigned char` for the input iterator.

Comment: Hmm, nope, `istreambuf_iterator<unsigned char>` doesn't work, but the implicit cast from `char` to `unsigned char` is probably not something to fuss over. https://ideone.com/1JgRkO

Comment: True enough. The lookup table approach is neat, too.